# Panoramic render not working

Tags: cycles-render-engine, hdri, panoramic

I'm trying to create a HDRI picture of the moon to use for a Fusion 360 render (so it has to have a 2:1 aspect ratio).

I've followed several tutorials, but no matter what I do, I'm just not getting a panoramic equirectangular view (neither in the viewport nor render).

Here are all of the settings I have so far:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The moon was made following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UAOy42TR_Rk), if that's relevant.

For some reason, no matter what I do, the render view does not change (I've played with Local Camera, Active Objects, etc.), so I'm really lost. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: tested it just now and it should work. Maby there is something else in your file, could you share it? (if so, dont forget to pack the image) Its not avaliable in solid view, but vieport render and render image should work just fine.

Comment: I've uploaded the file and image  here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IeaqJwp47kdlNlo1GBA_kwlYuwrTQGpb/view?usp=sharing and here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X7QHqdSYAhF3cSSLo-Dn8ouaB6y9EL0b/view?usp=sharing , respectively. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in the scene that could easily happen, but accumulate in this case.

1. the camera is not at location (0, 0, 0). The scene setup has a sphere at (0, 0, 0). The camera is suposed to be centered in this sphere. This can easily happen with "camera to view" on in the N-Panel > View and jumping in and out the camera with 0. Check out the transform in the N-Panel and reset it with hovering + backspace
2. facing the camera to your motive is preferable, because your moon  motive is very small and would be cut in half and be displayed at your image borders because of the 360 projection. sugestion rotation (90 ,0, -90) or rotate the texture in the material.
3. there is no lightsource inside the image sphere, so everything is black from the camera perspective. Dont put a lightsource inside, the bouncing will be very very expensive but instead use an emission shader instead of principled. This is getting even better: now you can render your 360 image with one sample and no noise because emission shaders are returning absolute values.

original problems:
[image]

solution:
[image]

Comment: Nice answer, learned a lot here :).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't quite follow. I tried moving the moon to a different position and the camera to (0, 0, 0) but this didn't make any difference. I purposely tried to distance the camera from the motive so that it's not cut in half, but I don't want it as far as it currently is :) Also, when I try the emission shader it's too bright (I'm probably using it wrong). Could you share the file please so I can take a look?

Comment: For clearing up some possible missunderstandings. Let moon at (0, 0, 0), camera also to (0, 0, 0) but with rotation (90, 0, -90). You can controll the brightness of the texture in the shader editor with a color > brightness contrast node. But also keep in mind that the emission shader outputs the texture 1:1 with its original brightness, maby you see it as diffrent because other softwares like photoshop dont handle the color space of hdris well.

Comment: (7 Days active) moon2.blend file: https://easyupload.io/8misyr